# javascript for a simple lightbox seems not to be functioning

Tags: javascript, youtube, lightbox

I'm new to programming unfortunately and so to help me I have been following some simple tutorials on youtube (in addition to following Treehouse lessons). The one I have been struggling with and can't seem to find a solution to is building a simple lightbox, well getting the click event to bring up the lightbox. I have checked all lines, syntax, whether I've omitted a ; or {}, thought maybe I had the javascript src incorrect, tried downloading, creating a js folder and linking to that, referencing google hosted javascript, checked firebug, tried different browsers, checked that the CSS is correct (which it seems to be as when setting the display to block it appears OK), thought maybe there is updated syntax rules (tried jQuery instead of $ but just can't see where I'm making an error. Probably I have omitted something really simple, so please forgive me in advance. The youtube link I'm following is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-uonF7Gdgw Have also checked the comments to the video to see if anyone else is having same problem, some are, but mostly everyone else seems ok, and no solutions posted for those not getting it to work!

Please see below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.lightbox').click(function(){
        jQuery('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear'); //fades in the backdrop and the lightbox - speed of 300, and displayed in a linear fashion. Only want the backdrop displayed with 50% opacity, and the box at 100% (see below line)
        jQuery('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
        jQuery('.backdrop, .box').css('dispaly', 'block'); //sets the appearance of the box
    }); 

});


</script>
```

Many thanks in advance, and thanks for great resource!
Nic

Comment: `dispaly` should be `display`

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! Unfortunately this silly mistake did not repair, I have written the code out a couple of times over to make sure, so I'm a little embarrassed to have made such an error! I have run a spell check again and no more such errors I am fairly confident this time...

Answer (score 3):

Lightbox is a JavaScript technique used to display images and other web content using modal dialogs where the image is shown up center filling most of the screen, and the rest of the window is dimmed out. Lightbox was originally the name of a specific JavaScript plugin. However, common usage of the term has evolved to encompass Lightbox-style JavaScript plugins and effects in general.

First we take some images (when we click on the images the LightBox will be shown). We will place this image in a

HTML code:

```
       <section id="examples" class="examples-section">
          <div class="container">

                 <h3 style="clear: both;">Four image set</h3>

                 <div class="image-row">
                       <div class="image-set">
                              <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-3.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                              <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Or press the right arrow on your keyboard."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                              <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="The next image in the set is preloaded as you're viewing."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                              <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Click anywhere outside the image or the X to the right to close."><img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                       </div>
                 </div>
          </div>
   </section>
```

Now add css code files for screen and lightbox. Also download lightbox.js and jquery library java-script files.